# Laravel 4 & Sentry

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, cartalyst-sentry

I've just trying to get my head round sentry... it's looking awesome.

I'm just wondering if there is a function to check if the user is currently logged in?

I've tried using the following:

```
if(!Sentry::check()) return Redirect::to('login');
```

But if the user isn't logged in I get the following error:

```
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Cookie\CookieJar::get()
```

Can anyone shed any light on this for me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like you are using a wrong version of Sentry. Edit your composer.json and use:

```
"require": {
    ...
    "cartalyst/sentry": "2.1.*",
    ...
},
```

And then

```
composer update
```